# How to find unnecessary jars in a project

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have some jars in my project. I want to know how these jars are used or what the effects will be if I remove them?

Comment: This will help http://java.dzone.com/articles/remove-unnecessary-jars. If you remove required jars, you are just going to blow up the application.

Comment: How do you build your project? Maven? Ant? Just Eclipse/IDE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it using [**loosejar**](https://code.google.com/archive/p/loosejar/).

> **It is a simple Java Agent that can be used to discover unnecessary
> jars lying on application classpath.** It performs per classloader JVM
> heap analysis and displays its results. loosejar can be safely used
> during development, QA, UAT or even in production as it doesn't modify
> the state of the JVM at all and adds no overhead.

**How to use:**

> 1. Start your application or application server with
>    -javaagent:loosejar.jar flag (loosejar.jar should obviously point to the correct path of the actual jar)
> 2. Exercise your application to make sure that the classes get loaded
>    into the JVM.
> 3. Get loosejar analysis results via JMX console (open jconsole and run
>    com.googlecode.loosejar.LooseJarMBean#summary() in MBeans folder) or
>    on application shutdown (via regular console log).

Answer (score 6):

You are using Maven, so you can use Maven's features to have a look what jars you need. Run the following in the root of your project:

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

And you'll see the line `[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:` with a list of dependencies that you don't actually need.

Comment: I need to run my project offline and gives build error with command mvn -o dependency:analyze.

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference if you were able to build it before. What is the error?

Comment: [INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin
Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin' not found in repository: System is offline.
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.0
 for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin

Comment: Aha, seems that you need to go online to let Maven download the maven-dependency-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UCDetector. See here [UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/)